# Genymotion GPS is not getting my current position

Tags: genymotion

As the title says, my genymotion is getting the static position declared in the gps options. Theres another option that I could get my current position? Im using cordova application testing with genymotion.

Answer (score 8):

Genymotion does not plug the GPS position to your computer's position.

If you want to customize your position you can do it on several ways:

- Use the GPS Widget (free feature) located on the right bar of the device. You can either set manually GPS data or use the Map view to do it easily
- Use the [Genyshell](https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/04_Tools/Genymotion_Shell/Genymotion_Shell.htm) (free feature) to script the positions injection.
- Use the [Java API](https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/doc/#genymotion-java-api) (paid feature). By including the JAR of this feature you can control the GPS and other device sensors. This feature is very useful to improve code coverage, for unit testing for example.

Comment: I don't know if there is anything relative, but when I use mini-mac on my work, the genymotion gets my current position where I work(connected by network). But if I use my mac(not connect to the network from my company) wont get it.

Comment: Genyshell link is not working. Returning a 404 Error. is the feature still available?

Comment: @eyal-lezmy The url is working and I'm able to set longitude and latitude manually but not able to do it automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I was using cordova geolocation plugin.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess,onError,options);
```

And I was also facing the same problem, It wasn't working in genymotion. Setting `enableHighAccuracy` to true worked for me like below.

```
    var options = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      maximumAge: 0
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

For programming, you could give fake position by using any app. For instance you might use [Fake GPS location](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps&hl=tr) to give static GPS position.